# Install netplan on Ubuntu 18.04 with no internet

Tags: networking, 18.04, apt, internet, netplan

I somehow seem to have damaged an installation on my Ubuntu box so that I have no internet access. I currently don’t see any Ethernet details if I run `ifconfig` plus it seems that `netplan` Is no longer installed.

I suspect I broke things by uninstalling Pi-Hole and some of its dependencies.

I am unable to reinstall netplan through `apt-get` through the traditional way given I have no internet access.

I have read that it can be possible to setup a local repository and point `apt-get` at it. Is this my only possibility or is there a way to install `netplan` on to this machine without internet access?

Comment: Are the packages still in your /var/cache/apt/archives? Also, consider reviewing the complete list of removals in the log: /var/log/apt/history.log. There may be more removed than you expect.

Comment: @user535733 there is one labelled netplan.io. And a few more. I suspect I could have removed more than just netplan so I will check the history log shortly. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the `.deb` package from a connected machine:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/netplan.io/netplan.io_0.40.1~18.04.4_amd64.deb
```

move it to Ubuntu Bionic (offline).

```
sudo dpkg -i netplan.io_0.40.1~18.04.4_amd64.deb
```

[List of dependencies.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/netplan.io)

Comment: Great thanks. As pointed to by @user535733 this package is still sat in my cache. Could I run the same command pointed at the the archive location?

Comment: @Bijington Yes you can.

Comment: I don’t appear to have iproute2 installed or in my cache so I guess I will have to go with the wget approach

Comment: This worked thank you. The only extra part that was outside of my knowledge was where to lookup the dependency URLs in order to pull those via `wget`. I found this site extremely helpful: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/